# Problem with understanding an incorrectly closed valid question

Tags: discussion, closing, specific-question

Just asked consecutively 2 questions relating to an issue I'm experiencing with Diablo 3. Someone suggested to ask another question for the very specific issue, which I did, but someone decided to close it pointing to original question as duplicate. How mad is this, I can't re -edit the second question and make it not closed again because someone decided so. What is going on?

[Diablo 3 PS4 Drowned Temple Main Quest Bug unable to progress](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/388014/diablo-3-ps4-drowned-temple-main-quest-bug-unable-to-progress)

Comment: Just a suggestion, but it might help of you'd usedsomethingtoseperateyourlinks.

Comment: I don't see where someone suggested that you ask another question. I do see [this comment](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/388010/diablo-3-ps4-drowned-temple-issue#comment546860_388012), where a user suggested that if you have an answer to your question, you should create your own answer to write it in.

Comment: @murgatroid99 Please view [this answer](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/388012/250180), specifically the last paragraph.

Comment: Oh, I did miss that part.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I believe Zoma was incorrect: if you have made progress on your current issue so far or attempted to resolve the issue yourself to no success, the correct course of action is to [edit your open question](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/posts/388010/edit) to state your attempt, what you've tried so far. The closed question was correctly closed as a duplicate. Please do not ask about the same issue more than once.

If you have made progress on your current issue *and* the progress solved your problem, post an answer to your own question clearly stating what you did and how/why it solved your problem. You can then accept the answer that most helped you, after 48 hours.

Questions on our network are ultimately for the community, not just you. Please, do come back every now and then to check for a better answer, and consider changing the accepted answer if a better answer comes in.

Comment: I agree that my advice was bad here. Just to explain why I did suggest it, my PoV is that the original question looked more like "What am I supposed to do here? Which quest step is next?", while a new one could have been more like "I don't have anymore quest or objectives to complete, what should I do to get it back to normal?".